# Ruby on rails Best IDE for Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am working over linux in our office for development over Ruby on Rails but in home i have Windows XP installed. It has different IDE installed for .NET and PHP development. So i don't want to get rid of those stuff also so kindly guide best IDE for Ruby on Rails Develpment over windows with MySQL as Database..

Comment: I like Netbeans. It is multiplatform and does have Ruby plugin.

Comment: @Vooza: Not anymore. Oracle dropped support for Ruby and Rails two weeks ago.

Comment: You should check jetbrains official student bundle offer. You can get online free student licence in 20 seconds for all these ides. [https://www.jetbrains.com/student](https://www.jetbrains.com/student/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also currently working on Linux and NetBeans. Netbeans also supports Windows and you can have PHP as well. But unfortunately NetBeans has discontinued their Rails support from version 7.0. So long term, it might be a problem.

Another one is RedCar (http://redcareditor.com/), this is also good.

Also Aptana RadRails (http://www.aptana.com/products/radrails) can also be used (they offer Eclipse plugin also).

And if you are looking for a paid one I would say go for Rubymine (http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/).

But as the final note. I have setup dual boot in my home laptop and do all the development except (.net) in Linux because you know Linux rocks :D

Comment: I don't think it is practical to do Rails development in Windows. I tried it and it took forever to get the environment started. Then some gems didn't work. It is hard enough setting up a Linux/Mac environment. I suggest getting another machine (even an old laptop), put a SSD in it, and install Ubuntu. Worked great for me and way faster and easier than windows. And 1/8 the cost of a Mac.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest RubyMine. Good Rails 3 support and provides a nice integration with your project elements and Rails tools.

Comment: Also has a good debugger, integration with git/github, supports haml/sass/less and much more.

Comment: I used Eclpse for 5 months, netBeans for 4 weeks and finally rubyMine.  I found rubyMine to be the best by a **long** way.  It works on Windows-Mac-Linux so your skills and knowledge transfer when you switch platform.  I also keep my vi/vim/macvim skills up though.  vi is best for some editing and server work, once you've replaced the escape key a few times after smashing it a million ties ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Aptana](http://aptana.org/)?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose that you use NetBeans with Ruby support. It is great and easy to use. I am using it.

I tried using Aptana, I just couldn't get it working.

Comment: Oracle dropped support for Ruby and Rails two weeks ago. That's an important factor to consider when choosing NetBeans. Obviously, the Ruby plugin is open source, so anyone can maintain it if they want to, but it's not clear yet whether anyone actually *does*.

Answer (score 0):

I am using netbeans for ubuntu as well as for windows. you can [download it here](http://netbeans.org/downloads/).

Comment: Oracle dropped support for Ruby and Rails two weeks ago. That's an important factor to consider when choosing NetBeans. Obviously, the Ruby plugin is open source, so anyone can maintain it if they want to, but it's not clear yet whether anyone actually *does*.